# Counts in bins using loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a list

```
a=[1,3,6,4,9]
```

I also have a series of bins `bins=np.linspace(0,9,10)`
and a bincount variable `bincount=np.zeros(9)`

I want to loop through the values of list `a` and based on which interval the value lies, I want to increment the `bincount` of that bin by one.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What sort of issues? why elif?

Comment: My list a contains some 10^8 numbers so it's not possible to load the entire list on memory, that's why I want to loop through each value at a time and put it in the appropriate bin.

Comment: Aha.  You should be able to load chunks that fit into memory - calculate the histograms for each chunk and then add them together

Comment: The complete truth is I have to generate that list a, it's not given. So instead of generating the whole list, I want to generate each value and put it in the appropriate bin and move to the next one.

Comment: You can even take a histogram of a single value, and just accumulate those histograms. It's probably faster to gather them into chunks for each histogram call though.

Comment: I see. How would accumulate the histograms of the single values?

Comment: Show more code and we can comment. This is too vague at the moment. What @JohnLaRooy is saying makes sense, but after that I'm not sure how to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to leverage `histogram`. This means there are less places for bugs in *your* code.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bins = np.linspace(0,9,10)
>>> bincount = np.zeros(9)
>>> import random
>>> for i in range(1000000):
...     bincount += np.histogram(random.randrange(9), bins)[0]
... 
>>> bincount
array([ 110579.,  111094.,  111231.,  111292.,  110875.,  111011.,
    111306.,  111356.,  111256.])
```

This takes a few seconds to run though. You can speed it up by reducing the number of calls to `histogram`

```
>>> bincount = np.zeros(9)
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     a = np.random.random_integers(0 , 8, 1000)
...     bincount += np.histogram(a, bins)[0]
... 
>>> bincount
array([ 110567.,  111021.,  110886.,  110846.,  111865.,  111113.,
        111284.,  110957.,  111461.])
```